# Dependency Injection for my custom UserManager WITHOUT Identity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am currently trying to make my own AccountController with its own UserManager in ASP.Net Core 2.1.
The UserManager should manage user related processes such as validation, registration, password change, etc in the database and I want it to be passed as a parameter in the AccountController constructor. I have already configured the storage with `services.AddDbContext<CustomDB>(...)`
The problem I cannot figure out is how should I inject the UserManager (what should its lifetime be - Singleton, Transient, Scoped). I do not want ot use Identity under any circumstances (that is the reason why I am creating a new one). In other words, I am looking for an alternative of `services.AddIdentity()` in order to inject my UserManager properly.

**AccountControler.cs:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
        private readonly IUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController(IUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        ...
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManager>();
    //or
    services.AddTransient<IUserManager, UserManager>();
    //or
    services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>();
}
```

Comment: When intent on reinventing the wheel, it helps to look at how the current one is built. luckily the source code is available. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/8ef14785a4a1e416189ca1137eb13f43c2f4349d/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs and they seem to add most everything as scoped.

Answer (score 2):

When intent on reinventing the wheel, it helps to look at how the existing ones are built.

Luckily the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/8ef14785a4a1e416189ca1137eb13f43c2f4349d/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) is available, and they seem to add most everything as *scoped*.

```
//...

services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();

//...
```

So in your case you can follow a similar pattern

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>(); // Add my custom manager

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your trying, look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818488.aspx).

Example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName,
      MagicCode = model.MagicCode };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded) {
      await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort of, but I want to do more stuff in there and still, as I mentioned in my question, I do NOT want to use Identity or anything related to it.